# Using chrome.runtime.sendMessage to chrome extension in FlutterFlow

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, web, google-chrome-extension

I've developed chrome extension and the website is ready; website is built in flutter flow.
The issue is that now I am trying to send message to my chrome extension using "externally connectable", now I am trying to send message from the custom action button in flutter flow but it is unable to read the "sendMessage", how to fix this and send message to my chrome extension?

What I have done

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:js' as js;

Future<void> newCustomAction() async {
  Map<String, dynamic> message = {'greeting': 'Hello'};
  String jsonString = jsonEncode(message);

  print('Message sent to extension');

  js.context.callMethod(
      'sendMessage', ['iedkcaeeboijleablfnnjjeihpgejjha', jsonString]);
}
```

Comment: It means `externally_connectable` didn't work or it's `matches` is incorrect. Also make sure you've reloaded the extension in chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm It says "sendMessage" is not defined, which I think there is no such API available in the  dart:js since everything is setup in chrome extension

Comment: The reasons sendMessage is undefined are listed in my comment. Just in case, it's chrome.runtime.sendMessage and not just sendMessage.